Disjoint union of countable copies of real line can be made into an immersed submanifold of the plane?
Consider $$S:=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2: y=0 \text{ or }y=\frac{1}{m}\text{ for some }m\in \mathbb N\},$$
with subspace topology from $\mathbb R^2$. This is, I think, the disjoint union of $\mathbb R\times \{\frac{1}{m}\}$ for each $m\in \mathbb N$ along with $\mathbb R\times \{0\}$. $S$ is clearly Hausdorff and second-countable since it is a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$. I want to define charts for $S$. Here is my try:
Each $\mathbb{R}\times \{\frac{1}{m}\}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$ via $(x,\frac{1}{m})\mapsto x$. Moreover, each $\mathbb{R}\times \{\frac{1}{m}\}$ is open in $S$ since it is the intersection of the strip $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2:y\in (\frac{1}{m+1},\frac{1}{m-1})\}$ (which is open in $\mathbb R^2$) and $S$. So, these are okay to consider as charts for any $p$ in any of these $\mathbb{R}\times \{\frac{1}{m}\}$ (I hope).
But for points in $\mathbb R\times \{0\}$, what should I do? Basically, I think that $\mathbb R\times \{0\}$ is not open in $S$; I can show that it is closed in $S$ (as it is the complement of union of all the $\mathbb R\times \{\frac{1}{m}\}$ which are all open) but that does not help me. Would be grateful for any help :)

You are right that $ \mathbb R \times { 0 } $ is not open in $ S $. An open neighbourhood of a point $ (x, 0) $ always contains a point of the form $ (x, \frac{1}{m}) $ for some $ m$ (large enough).

Any ideas how to construct charts for points on $\mathbb R\times {0}$ then?

Manifolds are locally connected. In your subspace, none of the points on $\Bbb R\times{0}$ has a connected neigborhood.  $S$ is not a submanifold. Drop "$y=0$" from its definition, and it would be.
